# Django. Go from one admin page to another

Tags: python, django

I'm completely new in Django. I have a large project. I need to add a feature: bulk edit using django admin panel. I figured out how to make another action, but I don't understand how to redirect a user from one admin page to another. How can I achieve this?
My action function:

```
def apply_to_brands(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    mymodels = django.apps.apps.get_model(app_label='brand', model_name='Brand')
    brands = Brand.objects.all()
    data = {
        'brands': brands,
    }
    return HttpResponse()<--- Here I need some logic that redirects me to another admin page and preserves info that queryset contains.
```

Comment: Does [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls) help?

Comment: Actually yes, probably. Is there anything like named_Url for adding one model to another? Using foreignKey field?

Comment: Changing a Foreign Key field dynamically would be very complex. If you can edit your question to show your models, or at least enough of your models to explain what you want to do, maybe we can find a different way to approach the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect a user using

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def apply_to_brands(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    mymodels = django.apps.apps.get_model(app_label='brand', model_name='Brand')
    brands = Brand.objects.all()
    data = {
        'brands': brands,
    }
    return redirect("YOUR_REDIRECT_URL_HERE")
```